# Short UINavigationBar with curved edges and transparent status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

How do I achieve this effect with a navigation controller.

I have just one VC embedded in a `UINavigationController` and is it presented modally over another VC. So far so good but I want to achieve a look something like below where the nav bar is shorter has curved edges and the status bar portion is transparent exposing the bottom viewcontroller's status bar.

[image]

This is what I have so far in the storyboard so far.

[image]

So far I have been able to achieve rounded edges for the navbar by subclassing `UINavigationController`. However I have no idea how to make the navBar shorter from the top:

```
class ComposeNavigController: UINavigationController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = false
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            view.clipsToBounds = true
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
            view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
            view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            view.layer.shadowRadius = 16.0
            view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
    }

}
```

Which works fine and curves the edges.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so here's what I had to do in addition to the `UINavigationController` subclass in my question. I had to make use of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` delegate in order to achieve what I wanted.

I created two class that subclassed `NSObject` and conformed to the above protocol.

First one is for `present` transition-

```
import UIKit

class ComposePresentTransitionController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.6
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let topOffset: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

        var finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
        finalFrame.origin.y += topOffset
        finalFrame.size.height -= topOffset

        toViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenBounds.size.height,
                                             width: finalFrame.size.width,
                                             height: finalFrame.size.height)
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            toViewController.view.frame = finalFrame
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.3
        }) { (finished) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {

        }) { (finished) in

        }
    }
}
```

Second for `dismiss` transition-

```
import UIKit

class ComposeDismissTransitionController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!

        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        var finalFrame = fromViewController.view.frame
        finalFrame.origin.y = screenBounds.size.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn,
                       animations: {
                        fromViewController.view.frame = finalFrame
                        toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (finished) in
            fromViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, from the view controller that's going to present this viewcontroller needed to conform to the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol and implement the `animationController:forPresented` and `animationController:forDismissed` methods like so-

```
extension PresentingVC: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                             presenting: UIViewController,
                             source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ComposePresentTransitionController()
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ComposeDismissTransitionController()
    }
}
```

Once that was done, the `PresentingVC` needed to set the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to `self` which was done in the `prepareForSegue`-

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        segue.destination.transitioningDelegate = self
    }
```

If you are a segue hater like me, then you can do this from an `IBAction` of a button all in the code too.

```
@IBAction func composeTap(_ sender: Any) {
        let composeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "compose") as! ComposeNavigController //this should be the navigation controller itself not the embedded viewcontroller
        composeVC.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thats it... now whenever the button was tapped to present the Compose screen modally, it would modally animate with the effect I desired. I added a little bit of bouncing effect just for fun :)

[image]